# Multimedia and Updated content is not reflecting when data is fetched using graphql api

Tags: content-delivery, graphql, content-service

I'm new to Tridion and I'm trying to created a page in CM and want to show that data into react using graphql. I'm able to get the data but facing issues with

1. Multimedia : I don't know how to display image.
2. When I Update content in the CM it is not being reflecting in the graphQl api.

Thanks in advance, Pardon for my english

Comment: Perhaps an obvious question here... for #2, have you published the content?

Comment: Yes I've published

Comment: Do you have someone at hand who is more experienced in Tridion matters? Please ask them to check you published everything correctly. Many things can go wrong with publishing (wrong target, wrong publication, forgetting to check in the component or page, to name a few).

Comment: Ok let me check again.

Comment: Feel free to share how your items relate, what content you are able to retrieve, and the specific query you're using. Specifically you're looking for the Tridion Content Manager URI (tcm-uri) on the Content Manager side and corresponding IDs from the endpoint. Also, is the Multimedia Component on its own, linked from another Component/Page, or referenced from a rich text format area?

Comment: Did you get a bit further with this, Sneh? Maybe you can ask a separate question about the images if you still need help.